# how to remove this symbol ₹ from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i have this ₹ symbol i want to remove it so that i can export my table with this symbol export is giving error

i'm trying something like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var table = $('#a').html();
    table.replace("₹",'');
   console.log(table);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">
<table  id="table">

  <tr>
    <th>vcajasjhhjd</th>
    <th>jdshbdfhfdh</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>abcd ₹  njdhjdrhjr</td>
    <td>jdhjhjfhjghghg₹jdshdfhs₹</td>
  </tr>

</table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the unicode character of Indian Rupee sign

```
str.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "");
```

The above code removes all unicode characters in a string. It should work.

Or to remove only ruppees sign

```
str.replace("\u20b9",'');
```

should work

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by selecting the `td` elements and providing a function to the `text()` method which removes the `₹` character from the current value. Also note that you would need to use a Regex with the global parameter set to that all instances of the character are removed, not just the first. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('td').text(function(i, t) {
    return t.replace(/₹/g, '');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">
  <table id="table">
    <tr>
      <th>vcajasjhhjd</th>
      <th>jdshbdfhfdh</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>abcd ₹ njdhjdrhjr</td>
      <td>jdhjhjfhjghghg₹jdshdfhs₹</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: console is not coming it is blank can you fix it

Comment: I didn't put a console.log in the code as it's redundant - you can see the output in the DOM

Answer (score 1):

Strings aren't referenced, so you need to assign the replace change in `table` again.

```
table = table.replace("\u20b9",'');
```

However the #replace will only replace the first occurrence of this string. A short way to replace all occurrences is by splitting them in this string, then joining each splitted part:

```
table = table.split('\u20b9').join();
```

I don't know what is the complete objective of doing this, though. Depending on your mights, there're better solutions.